# App Object in Electron Module and getAppPath throws Error

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I have a strange problem with my application. I get an error, and I can't solve it. First at all, I installed a new project, so everything is clean. Someone sent me this [repo](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) to use for an Angular, Electron and Nodejs Application. Everything worked fine, but then I decided to install an embedded database like sqlite3. For this I found NeDB, and the module is perfect for my needs. First I had the problem, has nothing to do with my general problem, that I can't create a database file. So I read that I can only create files in my application path, because something about Electron and that's working in a browser.

I found the `getAppPath()` method that is implemented in my `app` object from the Electron module. Here starts the problem. For hours I tried to get the application path from this object. Finally, I wrote this code.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
var nedb = require('nedb');
import { app } from 'electron';

import * as path from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
  app: typeof app;
  Database: any;

  constructor() {
    this.app = window.require("electron").app;
    this.Database = new nedb({ filename: path.join(this.app.getAppPath(), '/diary.db'), autoload: true, timestampData: true });

    var scott = {  
      name: 'Scott',
      twitter: '@ScottWRobinson'
    };
  
    this.Database.insert(scott, function(err, doc) {  
      console.log('Inserted', doc.name, 'with ID', doc._id);
    });
  }
}
```

And I get this error.

[image]

I found [this posting](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate/issues/104), but I don't really understand what the post is trying to tell me. I followed the links, but nothing seems to help. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: solved the Problem with changing this.app = window.require("electron").remote.app;

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't need to do `window.require(...)`. `require(...)` should be enough.

Comment: It took me also a few hours to find your question and answer. It might be a good idea to post it as an answer yourself and accept it. Don't be shy :-)